# Can AWS Cognito be used in a Node/Express/React app on EB?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cognito

I have a Node/Express server serving a React app all on a single Elastic Beanstalk environment. Is it possible to use AWS Cognito with this stack? Can the Cognito React component library be used without having an Amplify project, or do you have to do a bunch of custom stuff to communicate with the Cognito API? Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, because Cognito is publicly available. Also, AWS SDK provides components to do with Cognito too. Amplify works on top of AWS SDK